# testing mouse events in wpf

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, user-interface

for example, here's some code from an implementation of an attached behavior for a double click command:

```
private static void fe_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ClickCount != 2) return;
        ...       
 }
```

assuming you have a thin client with the bulk of the logic in a testable architecture, is there a cheap and relatively painless way to test logic that depends on user gestures like a mouse event?

Cheers,
Berryl

Comment: Can you expand a bit?  Are you looking to test the attached behavior or what the attached behavior does?  For example, if you're using MVVM, your attached behavior might be poking the ViewModel object though an ICommand or a data bound property.  If not, presumably your actual "do work" code isn't in the `MouseDown` handler but is in another method?  

Testing the UI gestures themselves can be quite a chore, but the work they do should be separated, at least by a method boundary.

Comment: The SuT in this case is the attached behavior itself. (not the ICommand / ViewModel interction, which is easy to test)